# Could not resolve archetype in maven project using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new in maven project ,when I create a maven project using my eclipse ide and select archetype is "org.apache.maven.archetype:maven-archetype-quickstart:release and and finish it there is a failed pop-up came :" could not resolve archetype"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to clean the local m2 repository by removing the folder .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetypes?

Comment: yes i have tried delete whole m2 folder and then again create project but still same error came

Comment: Please show the full error output and not only excerpts.

Comment: After click on Finish Tab :"could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetype:maven-archetype-quickstart:release from any of the configured repository" alert came.

Comment: Have you check the configuration given by "Window  > Preferences > Maven > User Settings"? Especially the path of Local Repository. An other point: have you tried to create a project with any other archetype, just to check that your ~/.m2/settings.xml is OK.

Comment: when i go to maven-->user setting a warning appears "user setting file doesn't exist". and yes there is no configuration file in .m2\repository\

Comment: Check if there is a settings.xml file under ~/.m2 (not under ~/.m2/repository)

Comment: Yes i tried to change archetype but same alert i got

Comment: no there is no setting.xml file under .m2 or .m2/repo/

Comment: So first thing first: create it! Even a minimalistic one as given in the Quick overview section here: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: but ,i am creating maven directory through Eclipse ide ,i mean it should be auto generated ..

Comment: It seems that something went wrong during Maven installation (or later...). The settings.xml should have been created then. Nothing to do with Eclipse. So now either you reinstall Maven or you manually create it.