# I am trying to setup a new project in Eclipse Giving error messge:setting up project

Tags: eclipse, maven, installation, project

I am trying to setup a new project in Eclipse as the previous project has been corrupted. Giving me error message: 
Could not resolve archetype
org.apache.maven.archtypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a network problem. If you are in a company, a proxy or firewall might block your attempts.

Talk to your admin.

Comment: Hello JF, I am working from home, No proxy or firewalls.  Can you please provide your advice.
I found this on the site attached:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365148/could-not-resolve-archetype-in-maven-project-using-eclipse
but not sure how to change location of .xml file



This is similar issue on StackOverfow and the solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365148/could-not-resolve-archetype-in-maven-project-using-eclipse

Can you please assist.  Thank you.

Comment: Hello JF, can you please answer one of my question.  This morning I deleted Eclipse icon and now NOT able to access Selenium.  I have looked in all my drives and trash bin but it's no where to be found.  Can you please, please assist me with finding and accessing Eclipse IDE.  I will be very grateful.

Comment: Go to the directory where you installed Eclipse and start `eclipse.exe`.

Comment: JF, thank you for your help.  What I have done is reinstalled Eclipse Neon to replace Eclipse Oxygen, I previously had.

Comment: Why not use a modern Eclipse like 2020-3?

Comment: Hello JF thanks for your reply and you recommendation to use Eclipse 2020-3.  I have created several projects, packages and classes in Eclipse Neon and wondering if I change to new Eclipse if it will be a chore to transfer to the new Eclipse.  Neon is working fine for now so wondering if I can keep using Neon?

Comment: Hello JF,  I have another question regarding one of my script.  I am trying for get all the src text on Amazon page, but my script is giving me several Blanks without src text.  Although I have added following code: if(! text.isEmpty());   But not helping.  Can you please assist.  Thank you .

Comment: 1. Commit your projects to git/svn (whatever you use) and then checkout into the new workspace for the new eclipse. 2. For another question, open a new question.

Comment: If you are able to, please let me know if I can please send you the whole script that I have used.  I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, but this an entirely new question. Please write a new question here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hello JF, I will write a new question here o Stackoverflow as this is a new question.  Thank you for the information and update.